# How to handle new incoming entries while paging through posts?

Tags: laravel, pagination

Let's assume I have a pagination like this

```
return App\Post::paginate(1);
```

After loading this someone creates a new entry in the database for posts. How can i ensure that the "second page" of my pagination does not return the first one again?

Will I always need to send a timestamp with every request to make an additional query before pagination is used?
like

```
App\Post::where('created_at', '<', $request->input('max_created_at'))->paginate(1);
```

Comment: Well, that's pretty normal behavior, I never saw any big websites that have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderBy`. You could do something like that:

```
// Get the last post (most recent)
return App\Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(1);
```

Or:

```
// Same as above
return App\Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
```

`orderBy` means all you result are sorted in your query. Hope it will help.

Comment: This will cause the exact problem i described: User a loads the first post - User b adds another - User a press "next" for the next post but will get the same post again

Comment: Ah OK. I did not read correctly what you wrote, my bad. So, uh, no, I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass any timestamp value to verify pagination. 
In the controller, in view file you need to pass result of this query.

```
$result = App\Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(1);
return view('pagination',compact('result'));
```

In view file you need below line for pagination work automatically as per Laravel syntax.

```
{{ $result->links() }}
```

Visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination/ how laravel pagination work.

Comment: I don't think you got my problem. I'm not even using blade views - that is for shure not what i 've meant

Comment: Can you  please brief more about your issue.